# Trenitalia, wrong name on ticket, problem?

Tags: trains, tickets, italy, trenitalia

A friend has purchased a Trenitalia ticket online.  The wrong name was entered by accident.

Is this a problem?  Are names/IDs checked on Trenitalia trains, or are tickets transferrable?  Does anyone have experience with this?

There was no special discount on the ticket that would require an ID check (such as student ticket).

Comment: how wrong is wrong?
Yvonne Chan when you're a Jack O'Neill or, just O'Neil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take it easy. Usually you can ask for a correction at the reception room of the railway station. If it is an obvious typographical error, you can even explain it to the ticket-inspector directly. Most of them will be kind enough.

Answer (score 4):

No guarantee obviously, but in a dozen of journeys on Italian trains with such online tickets (for the high-speed trains) I have yet to be asked for a proof of identity. I would not be too concerned about a wrong name, especially if the name still "sounds right" (e.g. not an Asian name for an obviously Italian person).

Also in the internal mailing list of the Italian institution I belong to, at times tickets are being offered for resale when the original purchaser is unable to use them, so safe to assume that it is not unheard of between people who know each other.

That being said, [officially the tickets do not seem to be transferable](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g187768-i20-k4649932-Trenitalia_ticket_holder_change-Italy.html), even when you book [the full price "BASE" fare.](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms-file/html/frecciarossa/Info_Tariffe_it_LeFrecce.shtml#BASE)

Comment: Timely answer! _

Comment: Italian style. Discovered a rule change on regional train tickets last night and going through old questions now. Also check [my late comment here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10793/32134) @Berwyn

Answer (score -2):

Noone ever controlled the name on the train ticket... Sure, if you are a man and you are traveling on a woman's ticket it might be a bit more risky, but otherwise, don't worry!

Comment: There's already an answer that says this....