# Can I travel Italian regional train tickets in the opposite direction of travel?

Tags: trains, tickets, italy, trenitalia

It used to be possible to purchase regional train tickets for a given milage (e.g. 100km) from newspaper stands / tobacco vendors at the station. You would purchase such a ticket for e.g. *Florence->Pisa* and could use it within some 3 months I believe, by [stamping it before the start of your journey](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10793/32134). Of course you were also free to travel in the opposite direction with the same ticket.

Trenitalia has recently changed [their rules for regional train tickets](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms-file/allegati/trenitalia_2014/area_clienti/4_Utilizzo_convalida_e_validita_dei_titoli_di_viaggio_tcom2014.pdf) (in an effort to stop fare evasion) so that any paper-based ticket (no matter whether it was purchased at the machines, ticket counter or from a newspaper stand as mentioned above) [is only valid for a certain date, until 23:59 on that day.](http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom/Treni-Regionali/Nuovo-biglietto-regionale) (Online tickets and tickets purchased via the app are mentioned as an exception but in reality those already are implicitly stamped as they can only be used during a restricted period of time.)

My question is, **can I still use a train ticket for the opposite direction of travel, e.g. *Pisa->Florence* when the ticket is for *Florence->Pisa*?** With the old kilometer-style tickets that was not a problem (I could also have used those for a different journey of the same or shorter length) but how about the new date-fixed regional tickets? In my example the ticket would be stamped (convalidated) in Pisa and I'd be on a train from there to Florence, the cost of travelling either way being the same.

Comment: I can envisage many complaints about this new system. Many people buy several tickets because it's hard to get tickets in some places and at some times.

Comment: The first complaint I heard about this new system was of the likes "how am I supposed to dodge the fair now by no longer stamping the ticket?!" @Berwyn, but I do completely side with you, I used to have a few extra tickets for the connections I travel a lot. I might now resort to the app whenever I can get it to work, or will loose time at train stations in line to get a ticket while the last train is leaving or pay the 5€ onboard surcharge. I mean, the last train of the day often even is past midnight. No brownie points for the Italians here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, not without changing your ticket at the ticket office, at a cost.**

I tweeted my question to the trenitalia account and their response was (rough translation of mine):

> You have to modify the ticket at the ticket office, see [info here.](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms-file/allegati/trenitalia_2014/area_clienti/6_Modifiche_al_contratto_di_trasporto_tcom2014.pdf)

The linked document ("modifications to the ticket", in Italian) basically says

- you can once ask for a modification of an unused ticket
- until 23:59 of the day preceding the validity day of the ticket
- changing the date, fare class, itinerary, origin and/or destination, class, number of persons, train category
- for a fee (unless when only changing the date) that is (roughly) 20% of the ticket price but max EUR 3.